# Merging many unique rows into one

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, subquery

I'm struggling to create a select query that merges/aggregates every row into a single row grouped by the column postfix_id.

```
|   postfix_id  |   initial_datetime  |    final_datetime   |  from_address  |   to_address   | response |

|   655CB4B10   | 2017-06-30 00:17:13 |         null        |      null      |      null      |   null   |
|   655CB4B10   |         null        |         null        | bob@domain.tld |      null      |   null   |
|   655CB4B10   |         null        |         null        |      null      | sam@domain.tld |   null   |
|   655CB4B10   |         null        | 2017-06-30 00:17:14 |      null      |      null      |   sent   |
|   C32AE57F3   | 2017-06-10 07:14:36 |         null        |      null      |      null      |   null   |
|   C32AE57F3   |         null        |         null        | joe@domain.tld |      null      |   null   |
|   C32AE57F3   |         null        |         null        |      null      | tye@domain.tld |   null   |
|   C32AE57F3   |         null        | 2017-06-10 07:22:54 |      null      |      null      |  bounce  |
```

Each postfix_id value is listed 4 times, and I need to consolidate each occurrence into a single row, thus removing the null values present in the remaining columns.

e.g. desired output:

```
|   postfix_id  |   initial_datetime  |    final_datetime   |  from_address  |   to_address   | response |

|   655CB4B10   | 2017-06-30 00:17:13 | 2017-06-30 00:17:14 | bob@domain.tld | sam@domain.tld |   sent   |
|   C32AE57F3   | 2017-06-10 07:14:36 | 2017-06-10 07:22:54 | joe@domain.tld | tye@domain.tld |  bounce  |
```

The table has upwards of a million unique postfix_id's, and I've traversed other similar posts, however, they have columns to compare and/or aren't related. My countless attempts using MAX and GROUP_CONCAT, have failed.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated. I feel as though it'll be simple, resulting in a /facepalm

---

Thanks again, I ended up with the following for my final needs. I hope this helps someone down the road..

```
SELECT postfix_id,from_address,to_address,remote_response,insert_datetime,initial_datetime,final_datetime
FROM (
SELECT
postfix_id,
MAX(from_address)     AS from_address,
MAX(to_address)       AS to_address,
MAX(remote_response) AS remote_response,
MAX(insert_datetime)   AS insert_datetime,
MAX(initial_datetime) AS initial_datetime,
MAX(final_datetime)   AS final_datetime
FROM email_outbound_postfix
GROUP BY
postfix_id
) as t1
WHERE insert_datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND CONCAT(from_address, ' ', to_address) LIKE '%sam%';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you showed us be accurate, then you can just aggregate your table on the `postfix_id` column, and select the `MAX()` of every other column:

```
SELECT
    postfix_id,
    MAX(initial_datetime) AS initial_datetime,
    MAX(final_datetime)   AS final_datetime,
    MAX(from_address)     AS from_address,
    MAX(to_address)       AS to_address
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    postfix_id
```

The reason this should work is that `MAX()` *ignores* `NULL` values in a column.  So assuming each `postfix_id` group only has one non `NULL` value, then `MAX()` would select it.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I had something very similar previous to posting, but I am experiencing an odd problem, where final_datetime, to_address, and remote_response are null in the output. I might have something weird causing a conflict. Looking now..

Comment: @cEMa Perhaps there is a problem with your source data.  Even if each group of records for a given column does not have only one non `NULL` value, we could still possibly write a query.

Comment: Without seeing your data I'm afraid I can't help.  Check the output and try to see which groups are having the problem.  Just because there is more than one non `NULL` value per group doesn't mean the query won't run, it just means you might not get the expected output.

Comment: I believe a WHERE statement was causing my problem. Thank you very much for you assistance!

Answer (score 1):

For this you can simply use `MAX` of Mysql

```
 SELECT postfix_id , MAX(initial_datetime) AS initial_datetime ,MAX(final_datetime) AS final_datetime ,MAX(from_address) AS  from_address ,MAX(to_address) AS to_address,MAX(response) AS response from table group by postfix_id
```

For more info about MAX please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply (speedy too!). Tim included more detail and also linked to that incredibly useful Rextester site, that I'd never seen before; so I had to give it to him.